# Выбрать единственное или множественное число сказуемого?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число

Когда планируе(ю)тся введение его в эксплуатацию и появление первой продукции?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем согласование **в ед. числе:**

Когда **планируется** введение его в эксплуатацию и появление (выпуск)  первой продукции?

Обычно ед. число используется **в случае препозиции** сказуемого относительно однородных подлежащих.

Также **нет тесной связи** между двумя событиями, они последовательно следуют друг за другом. Учитывается **одинаковая форма подлежащих** (сущ. ср. рода  в ед. числе)

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)